# DataGrip: Add Data to a Table in Snowflake with a UUID as default

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, datagrip

First of the DB is Snowflake.

DataGrip seems to generate INSERT-Statements with a DEFAULT for columns that have a default-value instead of omitting these columns. An example: First I create a simple table with 2 columns. `UUID` has `UUID_STRING()` as default and `TST_CHAR` is just a string.

```
   CREATE TABLE Tst_tbl (
     UUID varchar(36) default uuid_string() not null
    ,TST_CHAR varchar)
```

If I try to insert a value via DataGrip I get an error:
[image]

The problem is, that the column `UUID` is not omitted during the INSERT but is in the statement with DEFAULT. That doesn't work in Snowflake for UUID-Columns.

Can I somehow change this behaviour? How can I insert data in DataGrip into a Snowflake-DB with one of the columns having `uuid_string()` as default value?

The same thing works in DBeaver. DBeaver omits columns with DEFAULT values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is ia bug and we will fix it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-15031

Comment: It's fixed now. Expect in on of the follwoing releases.

Comment: @mocas The bug still exists. I updated to the current version, made a table with 2 columns (UUID with UUID_STRING() as default, and tst_char just a varchar). Still can't enter data with datagrip UI without an error. Is there a setting I have to change? https://i.imgur.com/B4K7xlK.png

Comment: Yes, it should be released in 2022.1 You can already try it: https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/nextversion/